# iAd for iPad distorts the portrait view

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, iad, landscape-portrait

I am trying to create a universal app. The app is in portrait mode only for both iPhone and iPad. I recetly added the iAd. When I test in the simulator, the followings are observed.

(When the ad is clicked, I do pause the game)

1. iPhone: The ad covers the full screen. I see both portrait and landscape ads. When the ad is cancelled, I get the original screen back in portrait mode absolutely fine.
2. iPad: I only see landscape ads. The moment i click on the ad, for a split second I see that my original sceen turns to landscape. Then of course the ad (which is always a landscape ad) covers the entire screen immediately. When I cancel the ad, I do get back my original screen in potrait mode. Howeve, all the pictures in the screen are in different places than they were just before the ad was clicked. In fact, most of the pictures are in place where they were put in the storyboard.

I am quite novice as far as coding is concerned. It would be highly appreciated if anyone can very clearly indicate the steps I need to take. Do let me know if I need to provide further info.

There are couple of related discussions I could see, but none I could understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what fixed the issue as I was trying different combinations. However, it has to do with the options in the utilities area when you select the iPad storyboard.